# Spring data JPA only one composite key is auto incremented issue

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I am using MySQL database.

In my table i there are two four primary keys, out of which one is auto incremented.

```
@Embeddable
    public class EmployeeId implements Serializable {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)// 
         This is just Pk  in mysql table
        **private int id;**
        // I have  tried and @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY),
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
        //and @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
        //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "id") @SequenceGenerator(name = "id", sequenceName = "id")
     **this is auto incremented and pk in mysql table**
        @Column(name = "gender_key", nullable = false)
        private int gender_key;

        }



        @Entity
        @Table(name = "employee")
        public class employee {
        @EmbeddedId
        private EmployeeId employeeId;

        private String emp_name;
        private String mobile_no;

        employee() {
        }}

        public interface employeeRepository extends
            JpaRepository<employee, EmployeeId> {
        }
```

In My Controller I want id after employeeRepository.save(bean); method because i want to save that id in different db .

logger.info("gender_key is --- > "+gender_key);

But I am getting always 0 value of gender_key.

The thing which I have tried is:

```
bean = employeeRepository.save(bean)
int gender_key= bean.getGender_key();
logger.info("gender_keyis --- > "+gender_key);
```

But still the value for gender_key is 0(Zero).
Or any Query which I have to write in repository .

How I can get the auto incremented value of gender_key which is inserted into MySQL table?

Please Help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your JPA `@Id` does not need to match the database PK column(s). So long as it is unique then that is all that matters.

From https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing:

> The JPA Id does not always have to match the database table primary
>   key constraint, nor is a primary key or a unique constraint required.

As your an auto-increment column is guaranteed to be unique then just use gender_key as your `@ID` and map id as a normal column.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class employee {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
   private int genderKey;

   @Column
   private int id;

}
```

To be honest I would find your schema confusing however.

I would also suggest reading the following:

https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a @GeneratedValue at the `id` field.
Depending on its values, you're free to choose a strategy for generation, like a sequences, id tables, an automatic internal id generation.
Last but not least GenerationType.AUTO will choose one of the mentioned strategies.
See the Javadocs for `javax.persistence.GeneratedValue` and `javax.persistence.GenerationType`.

Comment: I have tried 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
none of these is working

Comment: Please update your sample code with your attempts, then we'll most likely see what's the issue.

Comment: The things I have tried:   employee  bean=employeeRepository.save(bean);
int gender_key= bean.gender_key();
logger.info("gender_key is --- > "+gender_key);
I am not getting the value for this gender key which is pk as well as autoincremented
I have given the code above

Comment: Where did you put the @GeneratedValue? It needs to be@Id @GeneratedValue(...) private int id;

Comment: Plz check the question which is modified again
not only identity but sequence,auto and table i have tried all

Comment: Are you using Hibernate or sth. else as Persistence Provider?

Comment: using this as a persistence provider

Comment: Hmm, strange. Well, as per the specs composite keys cannot have partial generated values. So both ``id`` and ``gender_key`` need to be auto generated or none of both. Hibernate supported partial generation, but I'm wondering whether this is still true. Apart from this I wonder about your data model. IMHO one unique, auto-generated `id` field is sufficient to identify an Employee and I would recommend to let `id` be the only @Id field. Additionally a generated `gender_key` sounds strange anyway.

Comment: only gender key is auto  incremented and not id