# Composite id with a foreign key and a generated colunm, fail to save

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to figure out a way to manage a composite id on a table which contains an auto-generated value and a foreign key.
But, using ever `@IdClass` or `@EmbeddedId`doesn't work.
In both case I have an exception when trying to insert an entity in database.

I made a [sample project](https://github.com/vdubus/HibernateCompositeIdTest) to showcase my problem. This project is based on [Hibernate test case templates](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates).

### Common part:

The `Agent` entity to which all `Mission` should be linked.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Agent implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String login;

    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
}
```

### `@IdClass` case:

The **ID** for the `@IdClass`:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class IdClassTypeMissionId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private String agent;
}
```

`Mission` entity using the `@IdClass` annotation:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@IdClass(IdClassTypeMissionId.class)
public class IdClassTypeMission implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "agent_login", referencedColumnName = "login", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_id_class_type_mission_agent"))
    private Agent agent;

    private LocalDateTime dateEnd;
    private LocalDateTime dateStart;
    private String city;
}
```

The **test case**:

```
@Test
public void idClassTypeMissionTest() throws Exception {
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    final Agent agent = new Agent();
    agent.setLogin("jdoe");
    agent.setFirstName("John");
    agent.setLastName("Doe");

    entityManager.persist(agent);
    entityManager.flush();
    entityManager.refresh(agent);

    final IdClassTypeMission mission = new IdClassTypeMission();
    mission.setCity("New York");
    mission.setDateStart(LocalDateTime.of(2018, 12, 5, 7, 30));
    mission.setDateEnd(LocalDateTime.of(2018, 12, 6, 18, 30));
    mission.setAgent(agent);

    entityManager.persist(mission); // <- It fails here.
    entityManager.flush();
    entityManager.refresh(mission);

    final IdClassTypeMission result = entityManager.find(IdClassTypeMission.class, new IdClassTypeMissionId(mission.getId(), "jdoe"));
    assertNotNull(result);
    assertNotNull(result.getId());
    assertNotNull(result.getAgent());
    assertEquals("jdoe", result.getAgent().getLogin());
    assertEquals("New York", result.getCity());

    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.close();
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No part of a composite identifier may be null
```

### `@EmbeddedId` case:

The `@Embedded` part:

```
@Data
@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EmbeddedTypeMissionId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String agentLogin;
}
```

The `Mission` entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class EmbeddedTypeMission implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private EmbeddedTypeMissionId id;

    @MapsId("agentLogin")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "agent_login", referencedColumnName = "login", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_embedded_type_mission_agent"))
    private Agent agent;

    private LocalDateTime dateEnd;
    private LocalDateTime dateStart;
    private String city;
}
```

The **test case**:

```
@Test
public void embeddedIdTypeMissionTest() throws Exception {
    final EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    final Agent agent = new Agent();
    agent.setLogin("jdoe");
    agent.setFirstName("John");
    agent.setLastName("Doe");

    entityManager.persist(agent);
    entityManager.flush();
    entityManager.refresh(agent);

    final EmbeddedTypeMission mission = new EmbeddedTypeMission();
    mission.setCity("New York");
    mission.setDateStart(LocalDateTime.of(2018, 12, 5, 7, 30));
    mission.setDateEnd(LocalDateTime.of(2018, 12, 6, 18, 30));
    mission.setAgent(agent);

    entityManager.persist(mission);
    entityManager.flush(); // <- It fails here.
    entityManager.refresh(mission);

    final EmbeddedTypeMission result = entityManager.find(EmbeddedTypeMission.class, new EmbeddedTypeMissionId(mission.getId().getId(), "jdoe"));
    assertNotNull(result);
    assertNotNull(result.getId());
    assertNotNull(result.getId().getId());
    assertEquals("jdoe", result.getId().getAgent());
    assertEquals("New York", result.getCity());

    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.close();
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement:
insert into EmbeddedTypeMission (city, dateEnd, dateStart, agent_login, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-176]
```

### Analysis

With the `@IdClass` case, I was able to find a [bug ticket on Hibernate](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10956). What's why I was trying using `@EmbeddedId`.

At first, I thought that it was working: saving the entity using the `save` method from the `@Repository` seems to work. But, when trying to insert the entity using the `EntityManager`, it failed…

Did I miss something?
Is that a problem in my tests?
Any suggestion to make it work?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this but I have the impression that Autogenerated keys do not work on compound primary keys, if you run the application and check the DDL statements there's not an AUTO modifier for the id of IdClassTypeMission and therefore the errors "No part of a composite identifier may be null". The question is since your intention is to use an autogenerated PK why is the need to have a FK as part of the PK.

Comment: @garfield, that's because of the link between these entities. And I need to search on both the `Agent.login` and the `Mission.id` to make sure that the Mission does belong to the Agent. Unicity is only true for a composite key made from the `Agent.login` and the `Mission.id`. Currently I am ensuring it logically. But, I will need to divide my mission table in more chunk… And so I am trying to avoid having to verify each time that a row does really belong to the one requesting an action on it… :-/

Comment: Echoing the comment above I don't see any reason to bother with a composite key when the auto generated field can be used as an identifier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46358163/spring-data-jpa-only-one-composite-key-is-auto-incremented-issue/46370549#46370549 I don't really understand your comments above maybe you need to clarify your question.

Comment: @AlanHay, currently **I am using** only the auto-generated id. But, because of that, I have to specify each time that I am requesting a specific `Mission` by its `id`, and by it's `Agent.login` too! The reason is because, using only the auto-generated could allow an Agent to update a mission which isn't his… **This risk could be simply eliminated by using a composite id.** So, if I need each time to check on both the `Mission.id` and the `Agent.login` to find, update, delete a mission, isn't that we call a **Composite ID** to begin with?